# Equivalent bootstrap functionality for autoopen/resizable dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The following code works fine in jquery but  stuck with bootstrap. What is the equivalent code in bootstrap.

```
$('#window_open').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) component. Something like this:

```
<div id="boot_window_open" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Hello</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Bootstrap: Hello There</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Dq4Jw/1/) for comparison.